# Is $\left(\frac{a^2}{5}\right)=1$ for all $a$ not divisible by 5?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Note
$$\left(\frac{a^2}{5}\right)$$
is the Legendre symbol.

I used wolfram alpha to see if,
$$\left(\frac{a^2}{5}\right) = 1$$
and this is true for integers from $1$ to $10$ and it is except $5$ and $10$, which are divisible by $5$. So is this true in general for any $a$ not divisible by 5?

Comment: @zaira That is simply the definition of the symbol.

Comment: If you base it off the definition $\Big(\frac{a}{p}\Big) = a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ mod $p$, then the result follows immediately from Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: The legendre symbol is multiplicative in the upper entry, so yes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression
$$\left(\frac{a^2}{5}\right)$$
asks if there exists a natural number $x$ such that $$x^2\equiv a^2 \bmod 5,$$ from the definition of the Legendre Symbol. You simply let $x=a$ to satisfy the equation, so such an $x$ does exist, that is why Wolfram-Alpha returned a $1$ for this Legendre Symbol.

When $5 \mid x$, it is clear that $5 \mid a^2$, so the Legendre gives $0$ by definition.

Answer (score -1):

Euler's criterion tells us that the Legendre symbol is $\big(\dfrac {a^2}5\big)=(a^2)^\frac{5-1}2\equiv (a^2)^2\equiv a^4\equiv 1\pmod 5,$ by Fermat's little theorem.

This is true whenever $(a,5)=1.$

Thus the answer is yes.

---

Alternatively $\big(\dfrac {a^2}5\big)  =\big(\dfrac a5\big) ^2=1,$ as Lubin so insightfully notes (since $\big(\dfrac a5\big)$ is $\pm1$).